# GTA 5 Xbox one online accounts

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So I have two Xbox ones and I am planning on getting GTA 5 for both so I can play it where I go but I am concerned that if I am using the same Xbox account I will have two seperate GTA online accounts so does anyone know what it will do?

Answer (score 1):

You will have the same save game, synced to the cloud. I would also suggest you couldn't play on both with the same profile at the same time.
The Xbox you have as your home Xbox will be the one it works on offline and online. The other Xbox is the one only the person who's profile owns it can play.